# EE3 - Exception Caught error

Tags: error, sql

Getting the following error after moving site to local server. Same db and site files. DB settings configured. Any idea what the issue is?

> Exception Caught
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'agramarketingee.exp_plugins' doesn't exist: SELECT `plugin_package`
>   FROM (`exp_plugins`) WHERE `plugin_package` = 'markdown'
>
> mysqli_connection.php:117

Comment: did you ever get past this?

Comment: I am getting the same error. I am new to expression engine? Please post your answer if you had  already fixed it.

Comment: make sure to move any addons from both the system and theme dir. I think I was missing some of those addon files.